# Compile Vuejs element

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use Vuejs with some plugins.

There are two components

```
Vue.component('element-one', {
  template: '<h1>Element ONE</h1>',
}
```

And the second one :

```
Vue.component('element-two', {
  template: '<h1>Element TWO</h1>',
}
```

I want to be able to display the compiled version of element-one in element-two, I know there is something like:

```
var element = Vue.component('element-one');
new element().$mount().$appendTo('body');
```

But I'd love to have just the 'mounted' version, and not append it to any place.

Something I can play with in console.log ??

Answer (score 2):

I received an answer from https://gitter.im/vuejs/vue. You can get the element by

```
new element().$mount().$el
```